# How can i use a private installation of wxWidgets

Tags: linux

I have two installations of `wxWidgets`, one in `/usr/...` and one private.
I don't have permissions to change the central directory.
My question is how can i make my `private` installation the `active` one?

If i only add it to the PATH setenv, it dosn't work correctly since i'm missing the LIBS.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to do something like that is to add the folder with your "private" libs to your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable (assuming you're using `bash` and your shared libraries are in "/home/myLogin/wxWidgets/lib"),

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/myLogin/wxWidgets/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
```

From [The Linux Documentation Project - 3.3.1. LD_LIBRARY_PATH](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html)

> You can temporarily substitute a different library for this particular execution. In Linux, the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH is a colon-separated set of directories where libraries should be searched for first, before the standard set of directories

Comment: This helped. But i thought maybe there is a more generic solution like:  set_active <path>

Comment: @Kamil.Khoury What would `set_active` do (how is it more *generic*)? If you had root permissions, you could install your version (that's how things are usually "made active"). Or, you could edit "/etc/ld.so.conf" and then run `ldconfig` - but you would need root permission for that too.